# PROC NLMIXED "WARNING: Parameter vector 1 is not processed due to invalid or missing values."

Tags: sas

Observe the PARMS and BOUNDS statement in PROC NLMIXED:

```
proc nlmixed data=DATASET qpoints=100 noad;

     parms shape = 1.00  beta1=0.20 beta0=-2.70;
     bounds 0.50 < shape < 0.65, 0.10 < beta1 < 0.30, -2.8 < beta0 < -2.6;

 <snip>

run;
```

Which gives following Warning/ERROR:

```
WARNING: Parameter vector 1 is not processed due to invalid or missing values.
ERROR: No valid parameter points were found.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: The PROCEDURE NLMIXED printed page 2.
NOTE: PROCEDURE NLMIXED used (Total process time):
      real time           0.71 seconds
      cpu time            0.29 seconds
```

Google search turned up nothing for `WARNING: Parameter vector 1 is not processed due to invalid or missing values.`

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your initial values are within the bounds specified.  For instance your `shape` is initialized to 1, but your range in the BOUNDS statement is (0.50, 0.65).